# jquery click event doesn't work on a div loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an jquery script using .ajax that loads a new div containing the replied information. Part of the contents of that div is a link that says remove. When remove is clicked I want the parent div to hide. This doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.remove').click(function() { 
    $('.remove').parent().hide();
  });
});
```

This has no effect what so ever. This code seems to work if the div I am trying to work with isn't loaded with ajax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try live (added in 1.3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.remove').live('click', function() {
          $('.remove').parent().hide();
      });
});
```

Man: http://api.jquery.com/live/